# Flexbox and Float issues on Chrome/Firefox

Tags: css, svg, flexbox

There is a float issue when i use a flex svg image on chrome and firefox, only it showed correct on IE.

The rating is showed half on the other column.

Framework: Bootstrap 2

Bootplay: http://www.bootply.com/KQKMnpHtdL

**CSS**

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
#krating {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 4px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}
#krating-top {
  float: right;
}
.c-rating {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.c-rating__item {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 14px;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 14px;
  flex: 0 0 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: url('https://www.newf1.nl/components/com_kunena/template/crypsis/assets/images/stars.svg');
  background-size: 200%;
  background-position: 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.c-rating__item.is-active {
  background-position: -14px 0;
}
 .c-rating__item .is-active:hover {
  background-position: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<td class="span5">
<div class="krow">
    <a title="View Topic 'J SH hs cj sdchj dhs chds cjhsdc hds cjsd cjds cjs'" class="hasTooltip topictitle" href="/develop/forum/welcome-mat/50-j-sh-hs-cj-sdchj-dhs-chds-cjhsdc-hds-cjsd-cjds-cjs" rel="nofollow">J SH hs cj sdchj dhs chds cjhsdc hds cjsd cjds cjs</a>
    <div id="krating-top">
        <ul class="c-rating">
            <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="0"></li>
            <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="1"></li>
            <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="2"></li>
            <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="3"></li>
            <li class="c-rating__item is-active" data-index="4"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-phone">
    Topic started 3 hours 50 minutes ago,
    by
    <a title="View admin's Profile" class="kwho-admin" href="/develop/forum/user/237-admin" rel="nofollow">admin</a>
</div>
</td>
```

[See here the changes between browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7bPr.jpg)

Comment: Please post your code in the question.  Can you also clarify how the result you're getting is different than what your expected result is?  The preview in the bootply is the same for Chrome, FF, and IE.

Comment: @AdamKonieska i have updated my info

Comment: No one? i tried everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a width for your rating icons.

```
.c-rating__item {
  width: 14px;
}
```

You can see it working here in this new bootply:  http://www.bootply.com/12LbfUB0IF

*Note that you have 'localhost' images referenced in your CSS, so we aren't able to see them.

Comment: thank you, i paste the old bootply link, will update it, so someone else can use it to.